# Border-radius css rendering in PDF with RazorEngine

Tags: pdf, razor, rendering, css

I've built circles using css border-radius:50%, within an html page.
However, when I pass it to the programmer and he exports to PDF through RazorEngine the circles rendering is really bad. Have any idea why this happens?

I didn't wanted to use svg or images instead of css, but I guess that might be a last option...

A quick screenshot of the bad rendering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofmEK.png

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set **solid border** with the same color and try to render it. Border's width should not be 0.

Hope this helps you!